# what's the most efficient way to manage record position in a RDBMS table

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

let's say we have records in a table and we would like to be able to order (and reorder them).

the table could look like something like this, see below

```
                      id   Pos Level   parentId
Europe                18     1    0    null
    Germany            9     2    1    18
        Berlin         2     3    2    9
        Frankfurt     20     4    2    9
        Stuttgart     23     5    2    9
    France            29     6    1    18
        Paris         26     7    2    29
        Lyon          13     8    2    29
Americas              11     9    0    null
    USA               27    10    1    11
        New York      22    11    2    27
            Manhattan 19    12    3    22
            Brooklyn   7    13    3    22
        Los Angeles   25    14    2    27
    Mexico             6    15    1    11
    Canada             4    16    1    11
        Montreal      21    17    2    4
        Vancouver      3    18    2    4
Asia                   8    19    0    null
    China             14    20    1    8
        Beijing       17    21    2    14
        Shenzhen      30    22    2    14
        Shanghai      28    23    2    14
    Japan             16    24    1    8
        Tokyo          1    25    2    16
            Shinjuku  15    26    3    1
Oceania               24    27    0    null
    Autralia           5    28    1    24
        Sydney        10    29    2    5
Africa  

          12    30    0    null
```

where id is a unique id (can be anything), `position` the position of the element in the list, `level` depth level and `parentId` parent id (if exists)

Typically I would want the following method:

```
/**
  @param sourceId: id of the element to be moved
  @params targetId: id of the element which position needs to be overtaken
  @param aboveOrBelow: defines whether the old element (target) will be placed above or below the source element
  @return if successful, new position of the source element, if unsuccessful: message explaining why unsuccessful
*/
def move(sourceId: Long, targetId: Long, aboveOrBelow: Boolean = true):Either[Long, String]
```

what's the most efficient way to implement this or am I missing something? Is there already a built-in mechanism for such operations in (My)SQL?

constraints:
- end user who might be allowed to reorder do not necessarily see all records (e.g. only `asian` records)
- records can be added and deleted

=== edit ===
i rewrote the structure taking in account suggestions in the comments:

```
                      id   pos   parentId
Europe                18    1    null
    Germany            9    1    18
        Berlin         2    1    9
        Frankfurt     20    2    9
        Stuttgart     23    3    9
    France            29    2    18
        Paris         26    1    29
        Lyon          13    2    29
Americas              11    2    null
    USA               27    1    11
        New York      22    1    27
            Manhattan 19    1    22
            Brooklyn   7    2    22
        Los Angeles   25    2    27
    Mexico             6    3    11
    Canada             4    4    11
        Montreal      21    1    4
        Vancouver      3    2    4
Asia                   8    3    null
    China             14    1    8
        Beijing       17    1    14
        Shenzhen      30    2    14
        Shanghai      28    3    14
    Japan             16    2    8
        Tokyo          1    1    16
            Shinjuku  15    1    1
Oceania               24    4    null
    Autralia           5    1    24
        Sydney        10    1    5
Africa                12    5    null
```

Comment: do you really need the level column? It's implicit by looking at the parent(s). And perhaps "pos" needs to be only within the items who share the same immediate parent - their position overall is inevitably determined by their parent, after all. I think that would make your data structure more efficient and probably make your queries a bit less complex to implement. It also would match more closely with the scenario you mentioned where the person doing the re-ordering can only see a subset of the data.

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether this is specific to MySQL or any RDBMS.  Oracle, for example, has "connect by) and others use CTE (common table expressions) but MySQL really has no equivalent.  Your best bet is to use a temp table to contain the reordering and then either delete and reinsert or update the existing rows after your operations are complete. One more thing:  what version of MySQL are you using?  The poster below is correct if MySQL 8 or above.

Answer (score 1):

And for constructing the tree structure i would use recursive cte as follows. and construct it as a view

```
with recursive cte(place_name,id,parent_id,level)
  as (select place_name,id,parent_id,1 as level
        from countries_hierarchy
       where parent_id is null
       union all
       select concat(lpad(' ',a.level+1,' ')
                    ,b.place_name
                    )
              ,b.id
              ,b.parent_id
              ,a.level+1
         from cte a
         join countries_hierarchy b
           on a.id=b.parent_id
       )
select * from cte
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=334820e4e01cf8749c5abcaa447963a0